# Multiple-comparison p-value adjustment in meta-analysis

Tags: r, p-value, multiple-comparisons, meta-analysis, metafor

Do we need to adjust $p$-values for subgroup analyses in a meta-analysis?

I'm wondering if the typical subgroup analysis methods, like the ones in packages such as `meta` and `metafor` in R, account for multiple comparison adjustments similar to post-hoc tests.

I've seen questions on Stack Exchange about meta-analysis where multiple intervention groups are compared to a single control group, requiring adjustments for multiple comparisons, but that's not what I'm dealing with here.